# NPM install other packages also with current package install command

Tags: node.js, npm, meteor, dockerfile, npm-install

I have a project and it is dockerized. Project use Meteor and Nodejs. So my Dockerfile conatians both :

```
FROM geoffreybooth/meteor-base:2.0 as build
```

and

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node:14.21.3-alpine3.16
```

My project has also its package.json and has some dependencies. This project is alive for almost five years. But one of the customer want 0 H and C vulnerability in docker image. Project is on Meteor and Meteor support max Node14 and above base images have the vulnerabilities. So i have no chance to fix vulnerabilities except re-write without meteor. And i decided to change versions of packages whcih cretes vulnerability isues. I have done some updates in my Dockerfile and it worked perfect till now and i fixec 7 C and 5 H vulnerability. But i have difficulty with npm install. Now i have a package called trim(v0.0.1) and  i need to upgrade it to v0.0.3. PAckage is at 2 place:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/trim
/opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/trim
```

so in my Dockerfile i wrote these lines to fix it :

```
RUN cd /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/ && npm install  trim@0.0.3
RUN cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/&& npm install trim@0.0.3
```

When i build my image i've seen that packages not installed in current directory, nothing change, i can find the older version, but installed in another directory called :

```
/opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/remark-parse/
```

When i checked the directory before npm install command there are some files:

```
#40 0.485 index.js
#40 0.485 lib
#40 0.485 package.json
#40 0.485 readme.md
```

When i checked the directory after npm install trim command i have found:

```
#44 0.458 index.js
#44 0.458 lib
#44 0.458 node_modules
#44 0.458 package.json
#44 0.458 readme.md
```

and inside node_modules there exist new verison of trim. As you can see install trim command created node_modules and put trim new version in it although there was no node_modules package before install trim command (these are all coming from base images, i am not installing those by myself by the way) In its package.json's dependency part there exists trim@0.0.1 by the way. That is why it install i guess. But i dont understand why it didnt install newer version on its own path.

I've tried many things but no luck. I just want to update trim only in its path. Not to install it as a dependency for another package at same path. Does anyone know how to succeed it.

Here is my complete Dockerfile:

```
FROM geoffreybooth/meteor-base:2.0 as build

# Copy app package.json and package-lock.json into container
COPY ./sofie/package*.json $APP_SOURCE_FOLDER/
COPY ./sofie/postinstall.sh $APP_SOURCE_FOLDER/
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=ARG_NODE_ENV env NODE_ENV=$(cat /run/secrets/ARG_NODE_ENV)
ENV DISABLE_CLIENT_STATS 1
# Increase Node memory for build
ENV TOOL_NODE_FLAGS --max-old-space-size=4096

RUN bash $SCRIPTS_FOLDER/build-app-npm-dependencies.sh

# Copy app source into container
COPY ./sofie $APP_SOURCE_FOLDER/

RUN bash $SCRIPTS_FOLDER/build-meteor-bundle.sh

##  To get rid of underscore vulnerability
RUN cd /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/  && meteor npm install underscore@1.12.1
RUN cd /opt/src &&  meteor npm install underscore@1.12.1
RUN cd /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/ && meteor npm install fibers@5.0.0

FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node:14.21.3-alpine3.16

# Install system dependencies
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache python3 g++ make krb5-dev bash

# Create new non-root user to run app
RUN adduser -D -s /bin/sh sofieUser

ENV APP_BUNDLE_FOLDER /opt/bundle
ENV SCRIPTS_FOLDER /docker

# Copy in entrypoint
COPY --from=build --chown=sofieUser $SCRIPTS_FOLDER $SCRIPTS_FOLDER/
COPY --chown=sofieUser ./entrypoint.sh $SCRIPTS_FOLDER
RUN chmod +x $SCRIPTS_FOLDER/entrypoint.sh

# Copy in app bundle
COPY --from=build --chown=sofieUser $APP_BUNDLE_FOLDER/bundle $APP_BUNDLE_FOLDER/bundle/
## Meteor base image tan saçma bir şekilde bu dosya geliyor ve vulnerability içeriyor. Bu yüzden silindi.
RUN rm -r /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/email/node_modules/.nodemailer-garbage-xs9p72.levu

RUN bash $SCRIPTS_FOLDER/build-meteor-npm-dependencies.sh

## VULNERABILITY loader-utils
RUN cd /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/webpack && npm update loader-utils@1.4.2 --no-optional --no-save 
RUN cd /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/rasa-webchat && npm install loader-utils@1.4.2 

## VULNERABILITY nodemailer
RUN cd /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/email/node_modules/ && npm install nodemailer@6.6.3

## VULNERABILITY protobufjs
## Saçma bir şekilde /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm altında npm install çalıştırmak meteor klasörtünü uçuruyordu bunu başka isimle saklayıp tüm install lar bitince geri koyacağız.
RUN cp -r /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/meteor2 

RUN cd /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/ && npm install google-gax@3.6.1 && npm install proto3-json-serializer@1.0.3
RUN cd /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/@google-cloud/logging && npm install google-gax@3.6.1
RUN cd /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/ && npm install protobufjs@7.2.4
RUN cd /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/@grpc/grpc-js/node_modules/@grpc/proto-loader && npm install protobufjs@7.2.4
RUN cd /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/@grpc/proto-loader && npm install protobufjs@7.2.4

## VULNERABILITY prismjs
RUN cd /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/ && npm install refractor@4.5.0

## VULNERABILITY acorn
RUN cd /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/node_modules/ && npm uninstall reify && npm install reify@0.19.1

## VULNERABILITY node-fetch
RUN cd /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/isomorphic-fetch && npm install node-fetch@2.6.7


RUN cd /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/trim && cat package.json && ls
RUN cd /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/remark-parse/ && ls 
RUN mv /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/remark-parse/package.json /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/remark-parse/package2.json
RUN cd /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/remark-parse/ && ls -a
RUN cd /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/ && npm install  trim@0.0.3 --prefix /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/
RUN cd /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/remark-parse/ && ls -a
RUN mv /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/remark-parse/package2.json /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/remark-parse/package.json
RUN cd /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/trim && cat package.json && ls
RUN cd /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/remark-parse/ && ls


## Sakladığımız meteor klasörünü geri koyuyoruz.
RUN cp -r /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/meteor2  /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor 
RUN rm -r /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/meteor2

## VULNERABILITY for acorn 
RUN cd /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/meteor-babel && npm install reify@0.19.1

## VULNERABILITY is-svg
RUN cd /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/minifier-css/node_modules && npm install is-svg@4.3.0
RUN cd /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/minifier-css/node_modules/ && npm install postcss-svgo@4.0.3

## VULNERABILITY for fast-xml-parser
RUN find / -name fast-xml-parser
RUN cd /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/minifier-css/node_modules  && npm uninstall fast-xml-parser 
RUN find / -name fast-xml-parser

## VULNERABILITY for websocket-extensions
RUN cd /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/socket-stream-client/node_modules/ && npm install websocket-extensions@0.1.4

## VULNERABILITY acorn
RUN cd /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/modules/node_modules/ && npm uninstall reify && npm install reify@0.19.1 && npm install acorn@6.4.1
RUN cd /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/ && npm uninstall reify && npm install reify@0.19.1 && npm install lodash@4.17.21

## VULNERABILITY @babel/traverse
RUN cd /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/ && npm i @babel/traverse@7.23.2

## VULNERABILITY node-fetch
RUN cd /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/fetch/node_modules/ && npm install node-fetch@2.6.7
RUN cd /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/fbjs/node_modules/ && npm install node-fetch@2.6.7    

## VULNERABILITY update-notifier through execa
RUN cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/ && npm uninstall update-notifier && npm install update-notifier@4.0.0

## VULNERABILITY for execa
RUN cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/ && npm uninstall libnpx 



## VULNERABILITY marked
RUN cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/ && npm install marked@4.0.10 && npm install acorn-jsx@5.0.0 && npm install  espree@5.0.0 && npm install standard@12.0.0

## Some Vulnerability fixes delete fs-capacitor from apollo/graphql. We install it again.
RUN cd /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/@apollographql/graphql-upload-8-fork/ && npm install fs-capacitor@6.2.0
                      

## VULNERABILITY After nodegit installation minimist exists. So we put it here.
RUN cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tacks/ && npm install minimist@1.2.6
RUN cd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/tacks/node_modules/mkdirp/node_modules/ && npm install minimist@1.2.6 
RUN cd /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/ && ls
RUN cd /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/babel-compiler/node_modules/ && npm install minimist@1.2.6 
RUN cd /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/minifier-css/node_modules/ && npm install minimist@1.2.6 


## Saçma bir şekilde bazı npm install adımları react-syntax-highlighter klasörü içerisindeki package.json'ı da kuruyordu node_modules klasörünü remove edelim. 
RUN cd /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/react-syntax-highlighter && rm -r node_modules
RUN cd /opt/bundle/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/meteor/minifier-css/node_modules/is-svg/ && find . && ls


# Nodegit dependencies
RUN npm install --prefix $APP_BUNDLE_FOLDER/bundle/programs/server nodegit

# Those dependencies are needed by the entrypoint.sh script
RUN npm install -C $SCRIPTS_FOLDER p-wait-for@3.2.0 mongodb
# Give appropriate permissions to script folder for OpenShift
RUN chgrp -R 0 $SCRIPTS_FOLDER && chmod -R g=u $SCRIPTS_FOLDER

# Switch to non-root user
USER sofieUser

VOLUME [ "/app/models" ]
ENTRYPOINT [ "/docker/entrypoint.sh" ]

CMD [ "node", "main.js" ]
```